# Howto use struts2 with cache-filter

Tags: tomcat, filter, struts2

> > http://code.google.com/p/cache-filter/

How to use Filters with STRUTS2

Can somebody Tell me if Struts2 and google filter configurations in web.xml have any Impact ??

I am trying to use the same but not sucessfull.

with regards
karthik

Comment: what kind of caching you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Struts has built-in caching mechanism

Used by FilterDispatcher
If true then Struts serves static content from inside its jar.
If false then the static content must be available at /struts
struts.serve.static=true

Used by FilterDispatcher
This is good for development where one wants changes to the static content be
fetch on each request.

NOTE: This will only have effect if struts.serve.static=true

**If true** Struts will write out header for static contents such that they will
             be cached by web browsers (using Date, Cache-Content, Pragma, Expires)
             headers).

**If false** Struts will write out header for static contents such that they are
            NOT to be cached by web browser (using Cache-Content, Pragma, Expires
            headers)
struts.serve.static.browserCache=true

Source : [StrtusProperties](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/strutsproperties.html)

Comment: This is more specific to S2 internal caching mechanism like static content etc.it will not work if one want to use caching in general.

Comment: Thanks @UmeshAwasthi for correcting me, But we can implement a same kind of logic using interceptors right.

Comment: yes that's quite possible, in fact i am in process to write a plugin for same so as we can use any caching API with S2